# Map wildcard domain to Azure AppService

Tags: azure, subdomain

I want to map a second level of wildcard domain (i.e. * .api.mydomain.com) to my Azure AppService. I have already created CNAME entry for awverify.*.api.mydomain.com in GoDaddy. But, when I try to add *.api.mydomain.com on Azure portal, it's throwing following error

`Failed to update hostname bindings:
A CNAME record pointing from *.api.mydomain.com to myservices.azurewebsites.net was not found. Alternative record awverify.*.api.mydomain.com to awverify.myservices.azurewebsites.net was not found either.`

How can I map second level of wildcard domain (i.e. *.api.mydomain.com) OR how I can map to wildcard domain with virtual directory (i.e. *.mydomain.com/api) to Azure AppService?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, unfortunately I just found out myself when trying to migrate off of an older Azure option that this multi-level subdomain problem is not addressed in the new Azure Websites.

However... Speaking of the older Azure option...

An alternative solution is to use Azure's `Classic Cloud Service` option. We are currently using this and able to utilize as many sub-domain levels as we wish.

Answer (score 0):

Azure does not support multilevel domain names e.g. `a.b.example.com` and only supports single level domains, although that can be a wildcard

Comment: Thanks Michael for the info. Can we map virtual directory i.e. *.mydomain.com/api?

Comment: @Hitesh I'm not sure, you can map virtual directories, I'm not sure if they can be wild cards, I'd have to investigate - it is probably worth asking that as a new question